# Minion cannot find file on master

Tags: salt-stack

On Minion:

```
      ID: run_snmpv3_config
Function: file.managed
    Name: /tmp/run_snmpv3_config_cmd.sh
  Result: False
 Comment: Source file salt://files/run_snmpv3_config_cmd.sh not found in saltenv 'base'
 Started: 15:11:56.175325
Duration: 27.084 ms
 Changes:
```

On master we confirm that the minion does in fact see the file:

```
master # salt minion cp.list_master | grep snmp
    - files/run_snmpv3_config_cmd.sh
```

So why isn't it able to get it?

(In fact I wanted to use cmd.script but that errors out with `Unable to cache script`, so I tried to just copy the file, which doesn't work either as we see above.)

Comment: Do you have different environments (`saltenv`)? Which one is this minion part of?

Comment: @seshadri_c Thanks for your reply. I didn't show how I ran the state, which is the problem. I ran using `salt-call --local` for debugging. Of course that will try to get the file locally *facepalm* Still wrapping my head around this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called the state for debugging purposes on a client system using

```
salt-call --local state.apply teststate -l debug
```

Of course in this case it will look for file `salt://x` inside `/srv/salt` (or whatever the minion's config is) on the minion and not the master....